# Does ScrollableResults.last() read each record or skip directly to the end?

Tags: java, hibernate, mysql-8.0

When using a `ScrollableResults`, does a call to `last()` move directly to the last record or is it stepping through each record until it reaches the last one? E.g. is it performant, or not?

This is for MySQL 8 via the MySQL Connector for Java. Goal here is to get a total record count w/out issuing a second COUNT() query and also not iterating every record, and certainly not bringing them all into memory.

```
// just skip to the last record, don't pull each from the DB (??)
scrollableResultSet.last();
totalCount = scrollableResultSet.getRowNumber() + 1;
```

Comment: It's a complicated question, depending on the driver and other details. If all the results are in memory, then it's fast but you're using a lot of memory. If you have a cursor backing the `ScrollableResults`, it could give you performance comparable to native database cursor scrolling. This is tricky business, and the [drivers don't make it easy](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2826319/2541560).

Comment: Sorry, this is for MySQL 8 via the MySQL Connector for Java. I know there is still more to it. Goal here is to get a total record count w/out issuing a second `COUNT()` query and also not iterating every record, and certainly not bringing them all into memory.

Comment: Ah, the classic "get the total count while also getting the data", why didn't you say so. There should be plenty of duplicates or near-duplicates for ideas around here. IIRC a *simultaneous* count query is one of the best approaches if possible.

Comment: [This is probably the duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/168084/is-there-a-more-efficient-way-of-making-pagination-in-hibernate-than-executing-s).